# COBOL 85 yes or no input validation

Tags: cobol85

i just want to know how to make sure that the input entered by the user is only Y, y, N, or n.

I used this code:

```
01 ANSWER                PIC X.
    88 VALID-ANSWER      VALUE "Y" "y" "N" "n".
```

But still it doesn't work. The user can still type other characters.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When typing characters, the user can type whatever they want to (valid or invalid) your program can only validate the result *after* it has read the text. The appropriate validation would be something like: `IF VALID-ANSWER THEN whatever ELSE report error END-IF`. BTW - try tagging your questions with COBOL as opposed to COBOL85, not many of us watch for COBOL85 but several will pick up on the COBOL tag.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by using a perform loop:

```
at WORKING-STORAGE:
    01 ANSWER PIC X.

at PROCEDURE:
    PERFORM UNTIL ANSWER = "y" OR = "Y" OR = "n" OR = "N"
       DISPLAY "Question (y/Y/n/N) :"
       MOVE SPACE TO ANSWER
       ACCEPT ANSWER
    END-PERFORM.
    IF ANSWER = "y" OR "Y"
       do-something
    ELSE
       do-something-else
    END-IF
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The above `PROCEDURE` code will only work once. Use `PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER` to allow the code to be used without regard to the previous value for `ANSWER`.

Answer (score -1):

You just can't restrict the user input, except for uppercase.
What you can do is this:

At Working-Storage:

```
01 ANSWER           PIC X.
```

At Procedure:

```
ACCEPT ANSWER CONTROL "UPPER".
```

That will make sure whatever the user inputs, it's full uppercase. Then you check only for a "Y":

```
IF ANSWER = "Y"
  (do something)
ELSE
  (do something)
END-IF
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: The question was marked _COBOL85_, which is a standard. The phrase `CONTROL "UPPER"` is non-standard.